# Child doesn't continue running after receiving signal using pause()

Tags: c, signals, fork

```
  ...

  signal( SIGUSR1, sigusr);
  bla = 0;
  for(;;)
  {
    if(pid=fork()==0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"Child %d: Waiting in queue.\n",getpid());
      pause();
      fprintf(stderr,"im here"); //can't get to this line
      kill(deque(q),SIGUSR1)
      _exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
      sem_wait(&q2);
      enque(q,pid);
      sem_post(&q2);
      if(!bla)
      {
        bla=1;
        sem_wait(&q2);
        kill(deque(q),SIGUSR1);
        sem_post(&q2);
      }
      sleep(n);
    }
  }

  ...

void sigusr()
{
  signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr);
  fprintf(stderr, "Child %d: Got it.\n", getpid());
}
```

Child doesn't continue running after receiving signal using pause(), parent send signal to the first child, I get output "Got it." but can't get pass pause();. after the parent send the signal, the first child needs to send signal to the next child.. etc...

Comment: I rolled the question back to it's original form. It makes no sense to correct the errors in the question; it would cause the answers to look wrong, instead.

Comment: Notes: 1) use `volatile` for the `bla` varable. 2) don't call `printf()` from within a signal handler.

Comment: The `volatile` shall server which purpose, please? @wildplasser

Comment: It informs the compiler that the variable can be changed by another thread of execution, and the compiler should emit code to refetch the value from the variable every time it is needed, instead of caching it's value (for instance: in a register)

Comment: There is only one thread per process here. No need to synchronise  or protect access or whatever needs might apply when going multithreaded. To cut it short `bla` isn't "shared" in any way. @wildplasser

Comment: Yes you're right. @alk (I must have been hallucinating )

Comment: I want the code to be multi process... why you say it is not?

Comment: I said it's not multi**threaded*. Threads share the same address space and though can access the same (process) global variables, processes do not share the same address space, so for example each process has its own instance of `bla`, which can not be access from another process. A process' threads could , assuming it were declared global, which we do not know, as you did not tell us.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `pid=fork()==0` does not work as you expect it to. It assigns the valie of `fork() == 0` to the variable `pid`, because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for equality is higher than for assignment.

That means that `pid` will be either `0` or `1`, neither a correct process identifier.

Change to `(pid = fork()) == 0` instead.

Comment: Or simply do `if (!(pid = fork()))`

Comment: Thanks for that, but it is not the answer for what i asked.

Comment: @Bibrasnatho It is, if you use `pid` in the parent.

Comment: child still can't get to the line i specified in the code

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `pid=fork()==0` there is a race condition, the child may receive the signal before the call to `pause()`, and then wait for another signal in `pause()`.

To avoid this problem:

1. Block the signal using `sigprocmask`.
2. Check if is appropriate to wait.
3. Wait for the signal using `sigsuspend`.
4. Unblock the signal.